# Android canvas draw circle with different colors

Tags: android, geometry, android-canvas

I draw this circle and lines with only using canvas.

[image]

But I want to make every piece different color. Is there a way to draw 300,300 circle with 3-4-5-6..(every piece is equal) different colors.
For example first piece is Red, second is Blue, third is Orange .

Edit: I answered the question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for 5 pieces. You can change radius, degree and other parameters to make this dynamically.

```
private fun drawCircle300(): Bitmap? {

    var radius = 150f
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        (radius * 2).toInt(),
        (radius * 2).toInt(),
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )

    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)

    val paint = Paint().apply {
        strokeWidth = 3f
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
        isAntiAlias = true
    }

    val rect = RectF(0f, 0f, 300f, 300f)

    var degree = 72f
    var currentAngle = 0f
    for (i in 0 until 5) {
        if (i == 0)
            paint.color = Color.BLACK
        if (i == 1)
            paint.color = Color.BLUE
        if (i == 2)
            paint.color = Color.RED
        if (i == 3)
            paint.color = Color.YELLOW
        if (i == 4)
            paint.color = Color.GREEN
        canvas.drawArc(rect, currentAngle, degree, true, paint)
        currentAngle += degree
    }


    return bitmap
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar thing on a square image and it was easy by slicing the image into pieces and using `PorterDuffXferMode` filter on every piece. This may not work for you, reason being you've uneven pie shaped slices and not square/Rect. But How had I done it? see:

1. Create a Canvas object passing your image as bitmap:

   ```
   Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap1);
   ```
2. Create a Paint object and setXferMode as `SRC_ATOP`:

   ```
   Paint paint = new Paint();
   paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
   ```
3. Decide your image's slice's size and initialize a `RectF` object with it, here comes the issue with pie shaped sizes, if you can find a way around to this, you can do it.
4. Now, Loop between all the slices and put a color filter on it.

   ```
   paint.setColor("Your color here");
   //Move the rect to next piece using offset
   //i and j are loop variables as a 2D Matrix
   //dx is width of a slice and dy is the height of a slice
   rect.offsetTo(i * dx, j * dy);
   //Draw the colored Rect on the image
   canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
   ```
5. Finally, use the bitmap as required.

PS: This is not a new thing but I found it myself after investing a lot of time and reading many android docs, about 4 years ago. Seeing this answer it seems very easy, but finding the whole process was not.